# Passing context through createPage to use in a query, but a string is converted to a number so the query fails

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I have a page creatin function wuth this:

```js
createPage({
  context: { productId: String(productId) },
```

As you see, I even forced the ID to be a string, but the page template still receives a number

```js
const Template = ({ pageContext, data }) => {
  console.log(pageContext.productId) // number
```

And the following query that expects a string fails:

```js
export const query = graphql`
    myStuff(filter: {productIdentifier: {eq: $productId}}) {
      nodes {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Any ideas how I can force the `productId` to be a string?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString)?

```
createPage({
  context: { productId: productId.toString() },
```

Even the `productId` is not being casted, you can also try defining it as a `String` or `Int`:

```
export const query = graphql`
   query($productId: String!) {
     myStuff(filter: {productIdentifier: {eq: $productId}}) {
      nodes {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Use `$productId: Int!` otherwise but I don't know if this will match the filter though.

Another alternative is casting a new string variable before passing it to the context:

```
let productIdStringified = productId.toString()
createPage({
  context: { productId: productIdStringified },
```

Comment: Thanks for the ideas. `toString()` and `String` and creating the variable earlier, all give the same result, something happens when the parameter is being passed. The query accepts only a string, so defining it as Int gives me an error saying it is a wrong type.